# Speech to text api google Mp3

Tags: java

Quiero convertir un audio a texto, pero el audio esta en mp3 y tiene una duracion de una hora lo estoy haciendo de manera asincrono, que puedo hacer, tengo mi código de esta forma:

```
public class PruebasSpeech {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {  
        asyncRecognizeGcs("gs://cloud_at/2015-077.MP3");
    }

    public static void asyncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri) throws Exception {


        // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create()) {

            // Configure remote file request for Linear16
            RecognitionConfig config =
                RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
                    .setLanguageCode("es-CO")
                    .setSampleRateHertz(8000)
                    .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

            // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
            OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
                speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
            while (!response.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }

            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();

            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
                // first (most likely) one here.
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Transcription: %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarme qué error te esta arrojando al procesar el audio?

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar correctamente la transcripción de tu audio debes tener un *encoding* válido y coincidir con el que estás definiendo en las siguientes líneas:

```
...
        RecognitionConfig config =
            RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
                .setLanguageCode("es-CO")
                .setSampleRateHertz(8000) // En esta línea
                .build();
...
```

Si la Tasa de Muestra (Sample Rate) no coincide el SDK de Google arrojará un error indicando que no coincide con el recibido en la cabecera.

Para corregir ese error es necesario omitir esa línea o colocar el valor correcto.

Para conocer más información sobre este tema puedes consultar este enlace: [Introduction to Audio Encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding)

Para conocer los detalles de tu audio puedes utilizar el comando `avprobe 2015-077.MP3` para que te dé la información completa.

Si lo anterior no funciona siempre puedes transformar tu audio utilizando alguna herramienta como **ffmpeg**

Por ejemplo:

```
ffmpeg -i 2015-077.MP3 -c copy -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8k -ac 1 -map a 2015-077_out.MP3
```

Te dejo este enlace [Audio Types](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types) que te ayudará en caso de que tomes esta opción.